# How can I make hundreds of similar MySQL queries more efficient?

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have an array of information about links I've found on a webpage in a PHP script.

Each link needs to be inserted into a MySQL myisam table.

Right now, I loop through the array and run an insert query for each link.

Is there a more appropriate way to do this so that I'm using MySQL more efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert multiple values in a single statement using the following syntax:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
```

see [Section 12.2.5 of the MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html)

This is especially advisable if the MySQL server is on a different host than the PHP server: in the example above, you need only a single network roundtrip rather than three.

If network latency is not an issue (if the MySQL server runs on the same server as PHP), use prepared statements like this:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=test", "root", "");

$sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO links(title, href) VALUES(:title, :href);");

while ($link = getNextLink()) {
    $sth->execute( array( "title" => $link->title, "href" => $link->href ) );
}
```

Prepared statements are slightly faster when executed repeatedly, because the MySQL server has to parse the SQL and run the query planner/optimizer only once.

If the table has indices, you can disable them before inserting and enable them again after inserting, this makes inserting rows faster because the indices don't have to be updated after every insert (only possible for MyISAM, see [section 12.1.7 of the Mysql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html)):

```
ALTER TABLE links DISABLE KEYS
-- insert rows
ALTER TABLE links ENABLE KEYS
```

Answer (score 7):

You can insert several records with a single statement:

```
<?php

//  Our MySQL query

$sql = "INSERT INTO beautiful (name, age)
  VALUES
  ('Helen', 24),
  ('Katrina', 21),
  ('Samia', 22),
  ('Hui Ling', 25),
  ('Yumie', 29)";

mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

?>
```

Source: http://www.desilva.biz/mysql/insert.html

Comment: Is this typically considered an optimization in a situation like this?  Are there reasons not to insert hundreds of entries in one query? I'll test this and see if it works faster in my situation.

Comment: The only problem is running out of memory (PHP often has a strict memory limit at 16MB or so in the default configuration). Also, old versions of MySQL had a limit on the size of queries (also around 16MB as far as I recall).

Comment: I ran into an equal situation lately and experienced the following. When I run a query for each entry in my array it required 17seconds. When I always sent 5 entries at a time the process was nearly 5 times as fast. You might not want to send all entries at once, but as many as you think increases the speed to an appropriate level your application needs. Also when running the script on the live server it was again about 3 times faster than on my laptop with its slow HDD.

Comment: @T.BrianJones Yes, it is commonly considered an optimization. The reason NOT to use it would be a very HUGE amount of data... in this case, it would be better to put a limit on the number of records inserted each query (100 or 1000, for example...)

Answer (score 0):

A while or a for each loop is sufficient enough I would think for this, seeing as the information is going to be large and I imagine dynamic.

You can use one query but if you have hundreds or thousands of pieces of information, or if you are going to be constantly updating the database with new data, then an array with a for each or while loop is best for this. If its just a one off with only a few pieces of information then just write out the QUERY yourself as follows

mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (column1, column2)
  VALUES
  ('VALUE','VALUE'),('VALUE','VALUE')");